# Creating a mq listener for ibm-mq in Node.js

Tags: ibm-mq

Hi I am following amqsgeta.js from this link.
https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-mqi-nodejs/tree/master/samples
My requirement is to create a queue listener in Node.js, which should keep listening a queue and get the message, do some processing as soon a message arrives on that queue. I am able to  do that with MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED option.

```
gmo.Options = MQC.MQGMO_NO_SYNCPOINT |
                MQC.MQGMO_WAIT |
                MQC.MQGMO_CONVERT |
                MQC.MQGMO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
  gmo.MatchOptions = MQC.MQMO_NONE;

  **gmo.WaitInterval = MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED;**
```

This option keep connection open till there any restart of application.??Is there a better way of doing the same in Node.js application.

Comment: What do you not like about the solution you mention so we know what to suggest as alternatives? For example, if you don't want an infinite, and therefore non-interruptible wait, you can code a fixed wait, and run it all in a while loop which you can then test whether you want to break out of it every time the get breaks out of the wait.

Comment: I am not sure for MQC.MQWI_UNLIMITED option how long it will run like this. Is there a max Time limit for which the connection remain open without getting any messages. Like lets say 15 days no message and  then messages  start coming.??

Comment: Unlimited means it will wait forever, or until there is a failure, such as a loss of network connectivity or the queue manager is recycled. Using unlimited does mean that you can't gracefully "wake up" your application. If you choose to go for a limited wait in a while loop, then you can wake up your application more easily. Whichever you choose to do, you should still ensure you code for the failure cases I mention above. Those will happen regardless. If your application is a simple one, using MQCNO_RECONNECT might be all you need to do to cover that.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me in understanding  failure cases. I was looking for this information.